# Dynamic Type - InvokeMember on property setter throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I'm creating a class type based on key/values with the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a new class type using the schema info in a list of DataGridHeader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="header"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public Type BuildType(IList<DataGridHeader> header) {
        AppDomain domain = Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName {Name = "DynamicDataGridDataAsm"};
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName,AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder dynamicDataGridDataModule = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicDataGridDataModule", "DynamicDataGridDataModule.dll");
        TypeBuilder ivTypeBld = dynamicDataGridDataModule.DefineType("DynamicDataGridData", TypeAttributes.Public);

        foreach (var kvp in header) {
            ImplementProperty(ivTypeBld, kvp.Name, typeof(string));
        }

        ImplementProperty(ivTypeBld, "Value", typeof(string));

        return ivTypeBld.CreateType();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates propery Get/Set methods for a property by name and type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyType"></param>
    private static void ImplementProperty(TypeBuilder type, string propertyName, Type propertyType) {
        FieldBuilder field = type.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder property = type.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        MethodBuilder getter = type.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getterIL = getter.GetILGenerator();
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setter = type.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new Type[] { propertyType });
        ILGenerator setterIL = setter.GetILGenerator();
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, field);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, propertyType);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        property.SetGetMethod(getter);
        property.SetSetMethod(setter);
    }
```

Once the type is built, I'm attempting to populate the new property members with the dictionary values:

```
        static public object GetInstance(Type type, Dictionary<string, string> data) {
            //default construct the new type
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            object row = constructorInfo.Invoke(null);

            //Call set on each property
            foreach (var kv in data) {
                try {
//                    PropertyInfo prop = row.GetType().GetProperty(kv.Key, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
//                    if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite) {
//                        prop.SetValue(row, kv.Value, null);
//                    }

                    type.InvokeMember(kv.Key,
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                        Type.DefaultBinder,
                        row,
                        new object[] {kv.Value});
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
```

Either call to InvokeMember or PropertyInfo.SetValue result in an exception

"{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Bad method token.
   at DynamicDataGridData.set_Value(String )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
   at DSI.MobileClient.Models.DataGridDataTypeBuilder.GetInstance(Type type, Dictionary`2 data) in c:\DSISource_Global\v7\Development\Team5\DSI.MobileClient\Models\DataGridDataTypeBuilder.cs:line 33}"

I've been looking into what might be wrong in the .Emit section of the set property builder, but haven't figured what I'm missing.

The debugger reveals that the properties I'm attempting to set are there.

**Edit

Thinking that this line is incorrect:

```
setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, propertyType);
```

Trying to understand the copy and paste now - replacing the setter emit with this may be working:

```
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Your setter looks like strange, why do you load index 0 two times?

Comment: yes adding an edit now

Comment: The new code snippet is more like to the setter.

Comment: yes and the behavior seems to be correct